# How to compare string dates in scala without converting it into date type

Tags: scala

I have two string dates

a = '2021-05-23
b = '2021-04-24"

I'm trying to define a function that compares two string dates and returns true if b is one month greater than a.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Why you don't want to convert them to proper dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a little bit unclear, like do you mean the difference would be EXACTLY one month? Or does the predicate hold for the input examples you provided just because `5 - 4 = 1`? Anyway I think the code example below will give you the idea:

```scala
import java.time.LocalDate

def isOneMonthGreater(dateString1: String, dateString2: String): Boolean = 
  (LocalDate.parse(dateString1).getMonthValue - LocalDate.parse(dateString2).getMonthValue) == 1
```

You can also use `ChronoUnit`:

```scala
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit

val d1 = LocalDate.parse("2022-05-23")
val d2 = LocalDate.parse("2022-04-24")
val d3 = LocalDate.parse("2022-04-23")

ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(d2, d1)
// the above expression returns 0, since 29 days is actually 0 months!
ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(d3, d1)
// this one returns 1
```

Also dates as strings is not a good practice most of the time, so having inputs of actual date types is more recommended.

## Update:

---

Without conversion to date, you can parse it manually and there are many many ways to do this. And one thing to keep in mind is that as mentioned in comments, there might be some edge cases, but as far as I understood, this is just to explore around the language APIs.

1. using regex. You can define the format you're sure about for the date:

```scala
val pattern = "(\\d{4})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{2})".r
val dateString = "2022-03-02"

dateString match {
  case pattern(year, month, day) => ...
}

// or
val pattern(year, month, day) = dateString
```

But as mentioned, this is not safe, just to show that this approach exists.
2) splitting:

```scala
dateString.split("-")
```

And you can deal with the array elements as you wish.

Comment: So many corner cases.. don't do this manually, use libraries!

Comment: `java.time` is a part of the JVM standard library since JDK8 (required by Scala 2.12+) - unless you're on 2.11- it is already bundled in your environment, so I'm not sure that "using libraries" is the right way to call it. And yes, there are too many corner cases, e.g. what should be `"2020-01-30"` plus one month? February 30th is not a thing.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok correct. I did not say use `java.time` "as a library"! I just mentioned few approaches to the problem, and indicated since there are some edge cases, it's better to use a dedicated library!

Comment: It was a comment more towards @stdinstoud, it sounded like they wanted to avoid... external dependencies? While in fact `LocalDate` time is as external as `String` or `Vector`.